# What do I write in the views.py for my dashboard?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

I am trying to create a system where users can register their complaints and view and edit them as well. They can also view other people's complaints but not edit them. This is how my dashboard should look. I need to show the number of complaints that are registered by the user so far in the white box but I don't know how.
could someone please tell me how to do that?

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,null= True , blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
   profile_pic = models.ImageField(default = "msi.jpg", null = True, blank= True, upload_to= 
  'static/profileimages')
   first = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   last = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   mobile_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null= True)
   postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.first


class Complaint(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
   id = models.AutoField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
   reportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null = True, blank= False)
   eventdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
   event_type = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   device_problem = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   product_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
   exemption = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
   patient_problem = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   event_text = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
   document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents', blank=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.reportnumber
   @property
   def totalcomplaints(self):
       return Complaint.objects.count()
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   email = forms.EmailField()
   password2 = None
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name','email', 'password1']

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = '__all__'
       exclude = ['user']
       widgets = {
           'profile_pic': forms.FileInput()
       }

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
   input_type = 'date'

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Complaint
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
           'reportnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Report number'}),
           'event_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Event type'}),
           'eventdate': DateInput(),
           'device_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Problem'}),
           'event_text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 130px;width:760px'}),
           'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Manufacturer Name'}),
           'product_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Product Code'}),
           'brand_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Brand Name'}),
           'exemption': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Exemption'}),
           'patient_problem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Patient Problem'}),
       }
    
   def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ComplaintForm, self).clean()
       reportnumber = cleaned_data.get('reportnumber')
       event_text = cleaned_data.get('event_text')
       if not reportnumber and not event_text:
           raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
       return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
<!-- Middle Container -->
    <div class="col-lg middle middle-con">
        <div class="container mid-pink-con">
            <h1 class="we">We value,</h1>
            <h5 class="txt">Lodge your complaints here <br> and relex, now it's our turn.</h5>

            <input class="search" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder=" Enter Report Number" title="Type in a name">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark register-button">Register</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container mid-white-con">
            <p class="comp-txt">Number of complaints registered on your profile</p>
            <p>{{complaint_list.count}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the number of complaints by a single user? Say, the currently logged in user. Or do you want to show a list of all users with the number of complaints by each user?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show the number of complaints that are registered by the user so far in the white box but I don't know how. could someone please tell me how to do that?

The User model is linked to your Complaint model by a ForeignKey relation. By default, Django also creates a backwards relation `complaint_set` on the User model. You can query the complaints by a User `user` as follows:

```
users_complaints = user.complaint_set.all()
```

or get the total as

```
num_complaints_by_user = user.complaint_set.count()
```

You can also rename the backwards relation using the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument to ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you need to do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Count

users = User.objects.annotate(Count("complaint"))
```

and in your template, you can now access the number of complaints like this:

```
<p>{{object.complaint__count}}</p>
```

Comment: I added this as my view:  `def dashboard(request):
    users = User.objects.annotate(Count("complaint"))
    context = {'users':users}
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)`   but I'm still not getting any result

Comment: I do not understand why `context = {'users':users} `. Isn't that a profile for a single user?